# Laravel 4 ASmallOrange Mail Configuration

Tags: php, email, laravel-4

I have hosting with asmallorange.com and am trying to get Laravel 4 to work with it. I'm sending an email and it works fine when I use my stmp google mail setup, but I'm trying to use my hosting one. The configuration is listed below:

```
Secure SSL/TLS Settings
(Recommended)
Username:   no-reply@intellectproductions.com
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    burrito.asoshared.com
IMAP Port: 993
POP3 Port: 995
Outgoing Server:    intellectproductions.com
SMTP Port: 465
Authentication is required for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.
```

Based on those instructions, I composed my mail config like so:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'intellectproductions.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 465,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' => 'no-reply@intellectproductions.com', 'name' => 'Bunny Meadows'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => 'no-reply@intellectproductions.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => 'passwordhere',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Whenever I run my code though to send an email, it takes FOREVER and then gives me this:

> Connection to tcp://intellectproductions.com:465 Timed Out

Thanks for any help you can offer! I have tried ssl as the encryption as well and it acts like everything went through, but I never receive the email it's sending to.

Comment: Remove your SMTP password.

Comment: Woops.. thanks for letting me know. Looks like I'll change it just in case.

Comment: Updated my response since I meant to say SSL goes through, but I never receive the email it's suppose to be sending to.

Comment: SSL is now working... my IP was blocked from my hosting provider from the previous errors. Sorry! I assumed it was just not sending.